# Clickable text for Microsoft Teams Bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I built a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework in C# and currently access it in Microsoft Teams. Currently, I have a Hero Card that displays lines of text (id numbers), and I would like to make these "clickable" - when a user clicks on an id, the id is posted to the bot as input.

Creating buttons for each id is clunky and visually unappealing. Is there any way to turn the text into some sort of link so when an id is clicked it is sent to the bot?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, buttons are the only way to send inputs back to Bot. For your scenario, why don't you try out Dropdown option in [O365 Connector card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#office-365-connector-card)?

Here is the sample code: [O365ConnectorCardActionsDialog.cs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp/blob/1003c10c6b92e661e6e1f900c5e2434bb59a4afe/template-bot-master-csharp/src/dialogs/examples/basic/O365ConnectorCardActionsDialog.cs#L125)

Answer (score 0):

If you created your knowledge base using [QnAmaker](https://www.qnamaker.ai/) then it is very easy!
When adding answer in KB(Knowledge Base) follow below format :

[*text to show*]*(the link)* 
This automatically set the link in () to the text in [].
It will appear normal text with hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Use Markdown syntax. [Format your bot messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/format-your-bot-messages)

Hyperlink Markdown syntax :

```
[text for link](https://www.example.com/)
```